# Messages disappearing from queue after Azure Functions start

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

So I'm doing some testing with Azure WebApp + Azure Storage Queue + Azure Functions. Normally everything works great, however if I try to emulate the failure of the Functions App (with `Stop-AzureRmWebApp`) add message, start the Functions App, the messages get consumed, but not processed (and never returns to the queue). I'm using python to process data, but I don't think that matters at all. It appears that the messages just disappear.

I'm using S1 plan (not dynamic) with AlwaysOn.

Nothing reasonable in logs (these 3 executions are from before I disabled the Function App):

```
2016-11-30T11:33:48.216 Executing: 'Functions.somename' - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'queueName'.'
2016-11-30T11:33:48.216 Executing: 'Functions.somename' - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'queueName'.'
2016-11-30T11:33:48.216 Executing: 'Functions.somename' - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'queueName'.'
2016-11-30T11:33:48.216 Function started (Id=dc9fa205-6ddf-47e5-b529-90ccee2ddf0e)
2016-11-30T11:33:48.232 Function started (Id=5421bc7f-c438-4ffb-82e9-f7021604c247)
2016-11-30T11:33:48.232 Function started (Id=bb42ab71-3389-4668-a7f4-3d90d5cd96eb)
2016-11-30T11:33:54.576 Function completed (Success, Id=dc9fa205-6ddf-47e5-b529-90ccee2ddf0e)
2016-11-30T11:33:54.576 Executed: 'Functions.somename' (Succeeded)
2016-11-30T11:33:54.670 Function completed (Success, Id=5421bc7f-c438-4ffb-82e9-f7021604c247)
2016-11-30T11:33:54.670 Executed: 'Functions.somename' (Succeeded)
2016-11-30T11:33:54.685 Function completed (Success, Id=bb42ab71-3389-4668-a7f4-3d90d5cd96eb)
2016-11-30T11:33:54.685 Executed: 'Functions.somename' (Succeeded)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your messages *are* getting successfully processed by your function. Check the **Monitor** tab for the executions. The monitor tab is where you can find all historical executions for your function.

The log window in the portal is for **active debug sessions** only - i.e. you're live in the portal running/debugging your function. E.g. those logs disable themselves after some time when the portal is disconnected. Also, if you had the portal open on the log window and stopped the Function App, that could cause the log stream to be disconnected, causing the logs not to show in the window. To test that theory, after your stop/start you could pause/start the log stream again and it should show any recent executions that happened while it was disconnected.

Comment: Well, if they did get processed, I would see them in the SQL DB :) But I will test tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: btw, those are the logs from the drive, not from the portal

Comment: I've decided to accept this answer, although it didn't really help me, it might help others. For me after a few days of struggling with this issue it went away on its own. I really have little idea what was causing it and did it fix itself. Might be the Function app got upgraded to the newer version.